# How do I call this IEnumerator in unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ienumerator

So I am trying to Increment my total resources every 3 seconds by my PTick variables I tried using it via an IEnumerator and calling it inside the the start method but it only runs once so I tried it in the update and it runs as quickly as it can. is there any way I can get it just to run every 3 seconds. im happy to try alternatives so long as I can get it running every 3 seconds.

this is the script That I'm trying to get working

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Resources : MonoBehaviour {

private int foodPtick;
private int PowerPtick;
private int HappinessPtick;
private int MoneyPtick;
private int PopulationPtick;

public int foodTotal;
public int PowerTotal;
public int HappinessTotal;
public int MoneyTotal;
public int PopulationTotal;

void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(ResourceTickOver(3.0f));
}

void Update () {

}

IEnumerator ResourceTickOver(float waitTime){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
    foodTotal += foodPtick;
    PowerTotal += PowerPtick;
    HappinessTotal += HappinessPtick;
    MoneyTotal += MoneyPtick;
    PopulationTotal += PopulationPtick;
    Debug.Log("Resources" + "food" + foodTotal + "power" + PowerTotal + "Happiness" + HappinessTotal + "Money" + MoneyTotal + "Population" + PopulationTotal);

}

public void ChangeResource(int food,int power, int happy, int money,int pop)
{
    Debug.Log("Old Per Tick" + "food" + foodPtick + "power" + PowerPtick + "Happiness" + HappinessPtick + "Money" + MoneyPtick + "Power" + PopulationPtick);
    foodPtick += food;
    PowerPtick += power;
    HappinessPtick += happy;
    MoneyPtick += money;
    PopulationPtick += pop;
    Debug.Log("New Per Tick" + "food" + foodPtick + "power" + PowerPtick + "Happiness" + HappinessPtick + "Money" + MoneyPtick + "Power" + PopulationPtick);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the WaitForSeconds Yield Instruction? http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html

Comment: Hi Andrew.  Simply use `InvokeRepeating`.  So, `InvokeRepeating( "YourFunction", .1f, 3f);`  That's all there is to it.  Don't use coroutines.  (there is almost no reason to use coroutines in Unity except for extremely advanced situations).  To cancel the invoke, just CancelInvoke .. check simple doco

Comment: Don't use coroutines as they teach bad habits from the perspective of a c# developer and will most likely lead to a lynching in a regular c# job

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you aren't keeping your Coroutine alive after you have called it in Start. The call to StartCoroutine will execute once then return, so without a loop of some sort you will only have one call to the coroutine body.

Enclosing the yield statement in a loop will give you one iteration per the waitTime specified. In the Example below you can see that the console logs timestamp updates once every 3 seconds.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        StartCoroutine(ResourceTickOver(3.0f));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    IEnumerator ResourceTickOver(float waitTime)
    {
        while (true) // Do this as long this script is running.
        {
            print (Time.time);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
            print (Time.time);

            // Update Resources inside this loop or call something that will.

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First way using coroutine:

```
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(ResourceTickOver(3.0f));
}

IEnumerator ResourceTickOver(float waitTime){
    while(true){
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
       foodTotal += foodPtick;
       PowerTotal += PowerPtick;
       HappinessTotal += HappinessPtick;
       MoneyTotal += MoneyPtick;
       PopulationTotal += PopulationPtick;
       Debug.Log("Resources" + "food" + foodTotal + "power" + PowerTotal + "Happiness" + HappinessTotal + "Money" + MoneyTotal + "Population" + PopulationTotal);
   }
}
```

second way using Update:

```
void Update(){
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if(timer > waitTime){
       timer = 0f;
       foodTotal += foodPtick;
       PowerTotal += PowerPtick;
       HappinessTotal += HappinessPtick;
       MoneyTotal += MoneyPtick;
       PopulationTotal += PopulationPtick;
       Debug.Log("Resources" + "food" + foodTotal + "power" + PowerTotal + "Happiness" + HappinessTotal + "Money" + MoneyTotal + "Population" + PopulationTotal);
   }
}
```

third way with InvokeRepeating:

```
void Start(){
    InvokeRepeating("Method", 3f, 3f);
}

void Method(){
     foodTotal += foodPtick;
     PowerTotal += PowerPtick;
     HappinessTotal += HappinessPtick;
     MoneyTotal += MoneyPtick;
     PopulationTotal += PopulationPtick;
     Debug.Log("Resources" + "food" + foodTotal + "power" + PowerTotal + "Happiness" + HappinessTotal + "Money" + MoneyTotal + "Population" + PopulationTotal);
}
```